# JOGL polygon antialiasing

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to get anti-aliasing to work in my OpenGL application, but whatever I try, nothing seems to work!

My latest attempt is:

```
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
gl.glHint(GL2.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL.GL_NICEST);
```

Where (part of) my polygon code is:

```
gl.glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    gl.glColor3f(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f); // asphalt grey
    gl.glVertex3f(3.0f, 0.06f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(3.0f, -0.06f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-3.0f, -0.06f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-3.0f, 0.06f, 0.0f);
gl.glEnd();
```

But this has absolutely no effect! I still get this horrible gappy, jagged image:

[image: aliased OpenGL scene]

I've also tried

```
gl.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATION, GL.GL_ONE);
```

as per [this guide](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter06.html), but this just produces a black screen with nothing on it.

And I've tried

```
gl.glDisable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

before enabling blending, and once again it does nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For one thing, you need a pixel format with ***destination alpha*** to use the alpha saturation blend mode. This means that your framebuffer must store an alpha channel. Since there are not a lot of common uses for a destination alpha channel, often framebuffers are setup with only RGB channels. Can you add your pixel format to the question?

Comment: Have you read the article on the multisample extension? http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling

Comment: @ravuya: `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH` applies to any filled primitive. What it does not apply to are lines or points. There are separate smoothing states for those two types of primitives.

Comment: Sorry about that, edited my original post to remove that information. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I haven't explicitly set a pixel format - and I can't find out how to either. Could you provide instruction on how to set up the pixel format?

Comment: @ravuya This is meant for full-screen anti-aliasing which seems overkill for what I'm trying to do, but I'll look into it.

Comment: @CJxD: Unfortunately I have never used JOGL, so I do not know. Usually when you use one of these frameworks you have to select the number of bits per-component when you create your window. I would expect in a language like Java, that this would be done in a constructor.

Comment: @ravuya MSAA does seem to produce nice results for 4 samples or greater - with great results at 16x. My concern is whether the majority of users will be able to cope with MSAA or whether I'll have to start introducing settings to disable it.

Comment: It's managed in GLCapabilities and if it's not supported, JOGL will use the GLCapabilities instance closest to the one you requested.

Comment: Render offscreen to a surface 4 times bigger, than downsampling

Comment: @elect You basically just described how to do MSAA manually

Comment: Exactly, or you render to a texture and render the texture by setting your filters. Anyway you should avoid legacy OpenGL, here a modern [Hello Triangle sample](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial#Hello_Triangle)